# Loading other pages using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If my project contains 2 HTML pages, let's call them Page1 and Page2 and in Page1 I have a link to Page2 and in Page2 I have a JQuery file that needs to access Page1 and check if the link to Page2 is pressed (to do certain stuff) How do I implement this?

Here is what I've tried: This is the JQuery file on Page2

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    $(this).load("Page1.html"); // loads Page1 from current page - Page2
        $("#Link").click(function () { //if link on Page1 is pressed, do stuff
             //TODO
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Staying in page2 how could you check the link clicked or not in page1. Please clear your requirement

Comment: Rather than checking if this link is pressed or not in page 1 from page 2, why not just change your method of approach like, as you click page1, you write the code in page2 in such a way the link is **already** pressed.

Comment: Or better option, keep a global variable, and when you click the 'link to page2' in page 1, set the global variable to 'clicked'. After the page two loads, just check the global variable and continue from that.

Answer (score 1):

As @dvenkatsagar commented, use a control variable as global.

The `.load()` method has a callback function that you can pass as parameter. You have to do your stuff inside the callback. Also, to append the contents of "page1" to "page2" you must use an element, not the document itself. Check out the docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    // declare a control variable
    var clicked = false;

    // loads Page1 from current page - Page2
    $("#myDiv").load("Page1.html", function(){ 

        //if link on Page1 is pressed, do stuff
        $("#Link").click(function () { 

            // set control variable to true
            clicked = true;

        });
    }); 

});
```

Comment: What he wants, is after page 2 is loaded, he wants to check if the page 1 'link to page2' is clicked...

Comment: Oh, his code confused me. Then he wants to use something simple like a cookie!

Comment: Confused again, we are talking about working and loading contents in the same page... Even easier. Answer updated. Thanks for clarify @dvenkatsagar

Answer (score 1):

As kosmos said just set a cookie when user clicks on second link

```
document.cookie="click=clicked";
```

And read it in second html as

```
var status = document.cookie;
```

Answer (score 1):

After page2link is clicked, sets a global variable, page 2 loads and give a console.log output if it loaded from page2link.

Page 1:

```
<a href="page2.html" id="page2link">click me</a>
<script>
window.click_page1 = false;
// Jquery version : $("#page2link").on("click",function(){window.click_page1 = true;});
document.getElementById("page2link").addEventlistener("click",function(){
  window.click_page1 = true;
});
</script>
```

Page 2 :

```
<script>
if(window.click_page1){
  console.log("Clicked page 1")   
}
</script>
```